# io.to not sending to specific client

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am trying to send a message "newAllowedUserAlert" to a specific user. However the issue is that it is not sending at all to the user. To debug I checked if userToAllow was properly defined, and it was. I suspect the issue is I am setting a customId, but I make sure that no user comes twice so there are no duplicate IDs. Am I correct in believing customId is the fault, or is it something else?

Server side:

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.on("newUser", async function (userData) {
      const {isUserHost, customId} = userData;

      // Maybe only use original ID instead of customId?
      socket.id = customId;

      const [room, email] = customId.split(" ");
      const roomCriteria = {uuid: room};

      await Call.updateOne(roomCriteria, {
        $push: {
          currentUserEmails: email
        }
      });
      
      socket.join(room);

      if (isUserHost) {
        socket.on("newAllowedUserId", async function (userToAllow) {
          const emailToAllow = userToAllow.split(" ")[1];

          await Call.updateOne(roomCriteria, {
            $push: {
              allowedUserEmails: emailToAllow
            }
          });

          io.to(userToAllow).emit("userIsAllowedAlert", "");
        });
      };
    });
  });
```

Client side:

```
socket.on("userIsAllowedAlert", function () {
              alert("You are allowed!");
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a reference to each client's socket, that is indexed by customId and emit to them when needed.

```
const myClientList = {};

  io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.on("newUser", async function (userData) {
      const {isUserHost, customId} = userData;

      // Maybe only use original ID instead of customId?
      socket.id = customId;

      const [room, email] = customId.split(" ");
      const roomCriteria = {uuid: room};

      await Call.updateOne(roomCriteria, {
        $push: {
          currentUserEmails: email
        }
      });
      
      socket.join(room);

      if (isUserHost) {
        socket.on("newAllowedUserId", async function (userToAllow) {
          const emailToAllow = userToAllow.split(" ")[1];

          await Call.updateOne(roomCriteria, {
            $push: {
              allowedUserEmails: emailToAllow
            }
          });

          const userToAllowSocket = myClientList[userToAllow];

          if (userToAllowSocket) {
            userToAllowSocket.emit("userIsAllowedAlert", "");
          };
        });
      } else {
        myClientList[customId] = socket;
      };
    });
  });
```